# How to make TextView comletely ignore touches?

Tags: java, android, textview

I have this piece of code:

```
TextView result;

result.setClickable(false);
```

My `TextView` still reacts on clicks this way:[image: pic]. As you see the view gets shadowed which is not what I want.

I wander if there is a way to make a view completely unclickable. Also I don't need to use `TextView` but anything that can show digits.

`result.setEnabled(false);` doesn't help as well, as it just shades the view away, the effect is still present

Comment: try : `result.setEnabled(false);`...

Comment: Did you try result.setOnClickListener(null); ?

Comment: android:enabled="false" in your layout

Comment: @oguzhand -- It makes my app crash

Comment: @A.Yurchenko well, I don't know your full code, I cannot make any comment without seeing rest of your code and error logs. But normally, it shouldn't make your app crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Ripple Effect, to disable it you can do something like this:

```
<TextView
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
android:clickable="true"
/>
```

Ref : http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html,

Also, you can try to disable it `result.setEnabled(false);`

To disable the effect on GridView, you can try this code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    />
```

Comment: Anyway to do it from code? Also `setEnabled` just shades the views away, the Ripple Effect is still present

Comment: Your textview is inside some other component? Like recyclerView or something else?

Comment: `GridView` to be exact

Comment: I change my answer, try this one.